# An error occurred in the requested FTP operation. FTP Service (FTP07) 503 Invalid sequence of commands (AUTH SSL/TLS required prior to authentication)

Tags: c#

Here is my code:

```
FTPConnectionManager.Properties["ServerName"].SetValue(FTPConnectionManager, strFTPURL);
FTPConnectionManager.Properties["ServerUserName"].SetValue(FTPConnectionManager, strUserName);
FTPConnectionManager.Properties["ServerPassword"].SetValue(FTPConnectionManager, strPassword);
FtpClientConnection ftp = new FtpClientConnection(FTPConnectionManager.AcquireConnection(null));
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072 | (SecurityProtocolType)768; 
ftp.Connect();
ftp.SetWorkingDirectory(strFTPPendingPath);
ftp.GetListing(out folderNames, out fileNames);
//UnZipping FUnctionlity
ftp.Close();
```

And i get

> FTP Service (FTP07) 503 Invalid sequence of commands (AUTH SSL/TLS
>   required prior to authentication)

Comment: Are you using a Network Credential for username and password?

Comment: Yes, i am using username and Password for FTP